# Set multiple on EntityType per Entity instance

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

According to my problem domain I need an **EntityType** with a mix of **RadioButtons** and **CheckBoxes**:

Each `Selection` has a `multiple` property set to `true` or `false` based on the fact that it needs a `checkbox` or `radio`.

```
Product Selections:

[X] Selection 1
[ ] Selection 2
( ) Selection 3
(o) Selection 4
[X] Selection 5
```

`Selection` is an Entity and a `Product` can have multiple `Selection`s.

**ProductType**:

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('selections', SelectionListType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Product::class
        ));
    }
}

class SelectionListType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'class'         => Selection::class,
            'expanded'      => true,
            'multiple'      => ???????????
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }
}
```

I tried to use [Form Type Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html) with no success:class

```
EntityTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefined(array('multiple'));
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        if (isset($options['multiple'])) {
            $parentData = $form->getParent()->getData();

            $multiple = null;
            if (null !== $parentData) {
                $accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
                $multiple = $accessor->getValue($parentData, $options['multiple']);
            }

            $view->vars['multiple'] = $multiple;
        }
    }
}
```

How should I implement this?

Comment: `selections` should be a `CollectionType` with `entry_type` set to `SelectionListType`.

Comment: @JakubMatczak That would result in a Collection of list of all Selections. Please explain if you still think this could be a solution

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question and now I'm not sure what you're trying to do. I don't know how it could work, when you have some radio buttons and some checkboxes. It looks like your entity represents a form type's attribute instead of its value, and I don't know how checkbox/radio value relates to the entity.

Comment: Each `Product` can have multiple `Selection`s, either it is a checkbox or radio. A `Selection` is an entity, having some properties: string `title` & boolean `multiple`. What is unclear about this?

Comment: What it means that a `Selection` is selected? How is it reflected in the entity?

Comment: If a `Product` has a selection in its `selections` ArrayCollection, then the `Selection` should render as selected in view.

Comment: So where do the unselected `Selection`s come from if not from the `Product` entity?

Comment: Good question. There are complete list of `Selection`s through the entity `Selection` itself. And each `Product` has a private list of `Selection`s itself, through its private ArrayCollection: `selections` instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Basing on your question and comments, I think that the best solution is to  split that into two `EntityType`s  - one with `multiple` set to `false` and one with `true`.

Then using [DataTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) split the `Selection` collection into two arrays and put them to appropriate `EntityType`s. You also will need to merge data coming from these `EntityType`s into one collection in reverse data transformer and put it into your `Product` entity.

It would be best to do that in a separate `FormType` to get it working transparently.

Comment: Tnx for the idea, but it would be much helpful if you add some snippets to represent the actual implementation. Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: Everybody just gives theoretical answers but you cannot find anywhere an example.  Can you please demonstrate with some actual code?